# Data Pipeline load bulk tables in one time

Tags: aws, etl, redshift, pipelinedb

I am using AWS Data Pipeline for copying my RDS MySQL Database to Redshift. I need to create separate pipeline for each table and each pipeline create new EC2 instance. (Process takes time).

**Problem**

Is there any way to load whole database table into Redshift with single Data Pipeline . so i can schedule it and sync all my data daily with single pipeline.

NOTE: I have almost 250+ tables in DB that needs to be sync with redshift db (Almost daily). Or suggest any other better way for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I did this... i made a shell script and include all my tables there into a loop and store it in S3 and in pipeline ...i mentioned the path to script ...at scheduled time...the script runs and sync the data daily to Redshift. :) :Y